# VBA- Copy and filter a specific columns to a sheet from a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I already got how can i copy specific column from another workbook but now i also need to filter a specific column. I have tried this code but i encounter an error "Subscript out of range".

I need to filter Column C that contains "Mary" and copy its corresponding data. 
This is the sample of my code, I know there is something wrong with my syntax especially in using auto filter for COLUMN C and copying different column and paste it to another workbook. Please help me to make it right. Thanks

```
    Sub RAWtransfertoTRUST()


Dim MainWorkfile As Workbook
Dim OtherWorkfile As Workbook
Dim TrackerSht As Worksheet
Dim FilterSht As Worksheet


Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


' set workbook object
Set MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook

' set the worksheet object

Set TrackerSht = MainWorkfile.Sheets("Trust Activities Raw")
With TrackerSht
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 

End With

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

' set the 2nd workbook object
Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)

' set the 2nd worksheet object
Set FilterSht = OtherWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")


With FilterSht
 .AutoFilterMode = False
  .Range("B2:F").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Mary"
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 


End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 

    .Range("J1:J" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("G" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


                With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("N1:Q" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("H" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False



With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("T1:W" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("L" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False



With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("Y1:Z" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("P" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("AB1:AC" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("R" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False



End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: With FilterSht
 .AutoFilterMode = False
  .Range("B2:F").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Mary"
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


End With

Comment: I tried to add that code for me to be able to filter the column C but it will not proceed to run because of the error.

Comment: If you get a subscript out of range error, can you try to put the following line after `Set FilterSht = OtherWorkFile.Sheets("Raw Data")` : `Msgbox(FilterSht.Name)`

Comment: still getting the same error, i think my syntax is not right in filtering a specific column. Can you please give me an idea how to correct my syntax? thanks

Comment: But do you now get an error on the messagebox? Or still in the same line? The specific error would be more logical if the sheet can't be found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167127/discussion-between-alex-de-jong-and-aicirtap).

Comment: .Range("B2:F") is a [tag:google-sheets] syntax. In vba we supply an end row. btw, [tag:autofilter] requires a header row.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem, but I don't get the same specific error you got. I get an error because of the range "B2:F". I don't think this is allowed. If you change the code to Range("B2:F" & lRw) it would be allowed. You need to calculate lRw first then of course.

Comment: still getting the same error even though i tried to add your suggestion in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, i already resolved my issue. I just filter all the columns then delete the columns that i don't need. This is my sample code.

```
    Sub RAWtransfertoTRUST()

    Dim MainWorkfile As Workbook, OtherWorkfile As Workbook
    Dim TrackerSht As Worksheet, FilterSht As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook
    Set TrackerSht = MainWorkfile.Sheets("Trust Activities Raw")

    With TrackerSht
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

    Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)
    Set FilterSht = OtherWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")

    With FilterSht
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B1:W" & lRw).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Mary"
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy

      End With

 TrackerSht.Range("B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


    With TrackerSht
    .Range("G:I,K:M,R:S,X:AD").DELETE Shift:=xlToLeft

     .Range("E:E").Copy
     .Range("G:O").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
     .Range("G2", "G1000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
     .Range("M2", "M1000").Interior.ColorIndex = 41
     .Range("J2", "J1000").Interior.ColorIndex = 6


    End With


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

So, a few issues here.

In this code block:

```
With FilterSht
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("B2:F").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Mary"
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 
End With
```

You are missing a number in the range `B2:F`. If you want to filter the entire column, then both you should exclude the number "2" from `B2`. I assume that you were wanting to use the `lRw` that is actually on the next line, so this would need to go *above* your range line,  then you would need to include that with your `B2:F` by adding `& lRw`.

That line should now look like:

```
.Range("B2:F" & lRw).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Mary"
```

Also, keep in mind that this **is not** including row 2 in your autofilter. I assume you were wanting to filter row 2, so you would need to change it to `B1:` if this was the case.

---

Next issue is your copy / paste method. You are not pasting anything, because you never copied it. In the same **With block**, you can add this line: `.AutoFilter.Range.Copy`

---

Here's your final result:

```
Sub RAWtransfertoTRUST()

    Dim MainWorkfile As Workbook, OtherWorkfile As Workbook
    Dim TrackerSht As Worksheet, FilterSht As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook
    Set TrackerSht = MainWorkfile.Sheets("Trust Activities Raw")

    With TrackerSht
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

    Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)
    Set FilterSht = OtherWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")

    With FilterSht
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B1:F" & lRw).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Mary"
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


    With FilterSht
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("J1:J" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("G" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    With FilterSht
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"
        .Range("N1:Q" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("H" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    With FilterSht
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"
        .Range("T1:W" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("L" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    With FilterSht
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"
        .Range("Y1:Z" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("P" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    With FilterSht
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"
        .Range("AB1:AC" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("R" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Oh, and I *slightly* cleaned up your code formatting :D

Comment: Thanks @K.DAVIS i tried the code but the auto filter is not functioning and also there is no data copied from B1:F. Other columns just copy the whole data in the "RAW DATA". What do i need to copy is the data designated to "Mary"

Comment: @aicirtap Is "Mary" in column **D**? Because that's what your `Field:=3` means... The third column from *your starting column*, not from column A. **Edit** I just revisited your question, and Mary is in column C. So you need to change Field to **2**.

Comment: Thanks @K.Davis, but i have this problem whenever i try to run the code column (J1:J , N1:Q, T1:W, Y1:Z, AB1:AC ) just copied all the data from ("RAW DATA") it does not filter the corresponding data for Mary.